# How to set 'alert_light_frame' as background properly to the layout?

Tags: android

I am using a custom segment bar which contain three segments and I set `alert_light_frame` as background like `android:background="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"` but in 2.2 it is not fit correctly to the segment bar height, but in 2.3.6 its prefect. The height of background is more than segment bar.Can any one help me to solve this?

here is my xml layout of segment bar

```
<com.com.app.SegmentedRadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/segment_text" 
                 android:background="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one">
                <RadioButton android:id="@id/button_one" 
                    android:minHeight="35dip" android:text="one"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:button="@null" android:gravity="center" android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/button_two"
                    android:minHeight="35dip" android:text="two"
                    android:button="@null" android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/button_three"
                     android:minHeight="35dip" android:text="three"
                    android:button="@null" android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
            </com.com.app.SegmentedRadioGroup>
```

Comment: Could you put your code?

Answer (score 0):

Different versions of Android might have different versions of drawables.

When you want to use an android drawable, it is preferable to find it in your sdk (platforms/android-xx/data/res/) and include it in your project.

Therefore you'll use `@drawable/your_alert_light_frame` instead of `@android:drawable/alert_light_frame`

That way your app will be consistent no matter which android version is running.

So if the drawable from 2.3.6 is working fine, retrieve it from the sdk and use it.